# Adjacency Matrix not populating correctly python

Tags: python

I tried to implement a simple adjacency matrix to keep track of which nodes are connected to which nodes in an undirected graph. However, my adjacency matrix keeps screwing up by changing entire columns instead of individual cells. Here's my code:

```
def setup_adj_matrix(size, edges):
    # initialize matrix with zeros
    adj_matrix = [[0] * size] * size
    # edges is a list of tuples, representing 2 nodes connected by an edge
    for edge in edges:
        v1 = edge[0]
        v2 = edge[1]
        adj_matrix[v1][v2] = 1
        adj_matrix[v2][v1] = 1
    for row in adj_matrix:
        print row
```

for a graph with 3 nodes (0, 1, 2) and edges [(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)], I should be getting

```
[[0,1,1],
 [1,0,1],
 [1,1,0]]
```

However, I am getting all 1's. Any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange - note two in that paragraph might solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lists are all shallow copies of each other, so when you edit one you're actually editing each row. Try this for initializing the matrix:

```
adj_matrix = [[0] * size for i in range(size)]
```

Answer (score 6):

The multiplication operator with a list and an int returns multiple references to the same list, not multiple copies. Your array contains the same object nine times.

You can create the correct array with a double list comprehension:

```
def init_matrix(x, y):
    return [[[0] for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! though I think for my purposes, [0] should just be 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

The others answers do at good job at addressing your question, but if you are going to be doing any kind of heavy-lifting with your adjacency matrix, it might make sense to use numpy. As a bonus, the initialization is simpler and printing the array is built in:

```
import numpy as np

def setup_adj_matrix(N, edges):
    A = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=int)

    for (v1,v2) in edges:
        A[v1,v2] = A[v2,v1] = 1
    return A

print setup_adj_matrix(3,[(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)])
```

This gives:

```
[[0 1 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]]
```